# Searching firebase field when its value matches the users input

Tags: flutter, dart

When the searchPeople function is called, it doesnt filter for the users input unless I remove `.where('user_id', isNotEqualTo: user!.uid)`. I need this line so I don't display the current users information.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:snap_clone/widget/add_friend_widget.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AddFriendScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddFriendScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddFriendScreen> createState() => _AddFriendScreenState();
}

User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

class _AddFriendScreenState extends State<AddFriendScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  var controller = TextEditingController();
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('user_id', isNotEqualTo: user!.uid)
      .snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget currentPage = const AddFriendScreen();
    if (_currentIndex == 1) {
      currentPage = const AddFriendScreen();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.search_outlined,
                                  size: 30,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, right: 5),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        searchPeople(value);
                                      },
                                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      controller: controller,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                               
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Define the search function here
  void searchPeople(String query) {
    setState(() {
      stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('user_id')
      .startAt([query]).endAt([query + '\uf8ff'])
      .where('user_id', isNotEqualTo: user!.uid)
      .snapshots();
    });
  }
}
```

I tried removing `.where('user_id', isNotEqualTo: user!.uid)` and it worked but I need it so I don't show the current users information.